# Keeping an object made in OpenGL within the boundaries a window

Tags: objective-c, opengl, object, window

I have been working on a game using objective c and OpenGL.  I know how to create the object and how to make it move the way I want, but I cannot keep it within the window.  How do you keep the object within the window?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "object", and how you are rendering certain things, etc.

Comment: You don't create objects in OpenGL, you draw them. OpenGL does not maintain a scene graph or geometry persistence. OpenGL does not remember the things you tell it to draw.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL FAQ, [section 8.070: How can I automatically calculate a view that displays my entire model?](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm):

> The following is from a posting by Dave Shreiner on setting up a basic
>   viewing system:
>
> First, compute a bounding sphere for all objects in your scene. This
>   should provide you with two bits of information: the center of the
>   sphere (let ( c.x, c.y, c.z ) be that point) and its diameter (call it
>   "diam").
>
> Next, choose a value for the zNear clipping plane. General guidelines
>   are to choose something larger than, but close to 1.0. So, let's say
>   you set:
>
> ```
> zNear = 1.0; 
> zFar = zNear + diam;
> ```
>
> Structure your matrix calls in this order (for an Orthographic projection):
>
> ```
> GLdouble left = c.x - diam; 
> GLdouble right = c.x + diam; 
> GLdouble bottom c.y - diam; 
> GLdouble top = c.y + diam; 
> glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
> glLoadIdentity(); 
> glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar); 
> glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
> glLoadIdentity();
> ```
>
> This approach should center your objects in the middle of the window and stretch them to fit (i.e., its assuming that you're using a
>   window with aspect ratio = 1.0). If your window isn't square, compute
>   left, right, bottom, and top, as above, and put in the following logic
>   before the call to glOrtho():
>
> ```
> GLdouble aspect = (GLdouble) windowWidth / windowHeight; 
> if ( aspect < 1.0 ) { // window taller than wide
>     bottom /= aspect; 
>     top /= aspect; 
> } else { 
>     left *= aspect; 
>     right *= aspect; 
> }
> ```
>
> The above code should position the objects in your scene appropriately. If you intend to manipulate (i.e. rotate, etc.), you
>   need to add a viewing transform to it.
>
> A typical viewing transform will go on the ModelView matrix and might
>   look like this:
>
> ```
> gluLookAt(0., 0., 2.*diam, 
>           c.x, c.y, c.z, 
>           0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

a "look at" camera is a very convenient technique to make a viewer track an object (hence however the object or camera point moves, the object will stay onscreen). see 'gluLookAt' for a commonly provided implementation, most 3d helper code libraries will have one. You give it a desired camera point, object of interest, and 'up-vector', and it will create an appropriate world (camera transformation) matrix.

Otherwise if you're in control of the object, just don't move it outside of the initial frustum.